# wrong datatype after using a loop to create a list, then adding it to a dataframe

Tags: python

I am new to python and need help with the following problem
I have  a data frame like

| Employee number | Income | Working Years | etc. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2000 | 10 | ... |
| 02 | 3000 | 2 | ... |

I want to compare the wage of an employee to the average wage of their peer group.

Since I don't have information about their peer group, I used I use Kmodes clustering (based on factors likely to impact wages) to create clusters of employees and used those as the peer group. I'm not sure if this is an appropriate method, but I ended up with a dataframe like

| Employee number | Income | Working Years | Cluster |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2000 | 10 | 1 |
| 02 | 3000 | 2 | 0 |

I then calculated the average income of each of the clusters and subtracted each employee's wage from the appropriate average

my code is below;

```
compare=[]

for w in df['cluster']:
    if w == 0:
        compare.append(1000-df['Income'])
    elif x== 1:
        compare.append(2000-df['Income'])
    elif x== 2:
        compare.append(3000-df['Income'])
```

I want to add the 'compare' column to my original dataframe, so I can end up with

| Employee number | Income | Working Years | Compare |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2000 | 10 | 200 |
| 02 | 3000 | 2 | -100 |

so I tryed

df['compare']= compare

I need the column's datatype to be float, but it's coming out as an object, how can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: You really shouldn't be using loops for this. Learn to use vectorized operations on dataframes wherever possible. So, all you need is something like `df['Compare'] = df['cluster'].map({0:1000, 1:2000, 2:3000}) - df['Income]`

Comment: But also, please **always** provide a [mcve]. Please actually provide code that builds an example dataframe so that we can run the code and see what you are doing. [Here are some tips specifically for pandas related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Note, doing something like `1000-df['Income']` doesn't make sense, that would append a `pd.Series` object to your list. But you want the corresponding value from that same row!

Comment: Thanks  @juanpa.arrivillaga, I will look up vectorized operations, and provide more information next time